# Case statement won't return a value when one select query doesn't populate

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I tried asking this before with more specific queries, but I want to break it down with a very simple theoretical query to ask why.

When the second table t2 doesn't populate due to a where condition, then the case statement breaks down.

Assume that tblA only has one row

This will work: returns 1

```
DECLARE @numA int SET @numA=1
DECLARE @numB int SET @numB=1
DECLARE @numC int SET @numC=2

SELECT
    CASE WHEN(t1.v1=1 or t2.v2=1)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS Test1
FROM
   (SELECT 1 as v1
   FROM tblA
   WHERE @numA=@numB) t1,
   (SELECT 0 as v2
   FROM tblA
   WHERE @numA<>@numC) t2
```

This will not work because t2 won't populate:

```
DECLARE @numA int SET @numA=1
DECLARE @numB int SET @numB=1
DECLARE @numC int SET @numC=2

SELECT
    CASE WHEN(t1.v1=1 or t2.v2=1)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS Test1
FROM
   (SELECT 1 as v1
   FROM tblA
   WHERE @numA=@numB) t1,
   (SELECT 0 as v2
   FROM tblA
   WHERE @numA=@numC) t2
```

How can I make this work!? Thanks guys, I've tried

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense at all.  You are trying to select a fixed value from a table based on a where condition of variables being equal.  I would suggest you show an actual query of what you are attempting.  What you have is nothing more than an IF/ELSE test at worst case.

Comment: Agreed. What are you actually trying to do?  If you use an `FULL OUTER JOIN` between your two derived tables, with some equally nonsense join (like `ON 1=1`) you can get a result from your query, but it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508299/case-statements-using-variables-not-working

this is my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cross join where one side returns 0 rows. This returns 0 rows when combined, too. Consider this:

```
SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Results:

```
a
----
1
```

Now consider the case where the result returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 2;
```

Results:

```
a
----
```

Now, cross join them, either implicitly:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 1) AS t1,
(SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 2) AS t2;
```

Or explicitly:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 1) AS t1
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT a = 2 WHERE 1 = 2) AS t2;
```

In both cases, you get zero rows, because the concept of a cross join is "take every row from one side, and produce a row for every row on the other side." Since there are no rows on one side, there are no rows, period. This is like multiplying any number * 0. Doesn't matter if the source is 1 or 50 or 6000, that number times zero is still zero. So take it a step further:

```
SELECT a = CASE WHEN t1.a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM
(SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 1) AS t1
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT a = 2 WHERE 1 = 2) AS t2;
```

This still yields 0 rows, so there is nothing to produce from the `CASE` expression. Perhaps what you meant was something like this:

```
SELECT a = CASE WHEN t1.a = 1 OR t2.a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM
(SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 1) AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT a = 2 WHERE 1 = 2) AS t2
ON 1 = 1;
```

However, I have to agree with the comments. Instead of making up nonsense queries to try to understand behavior, why don't you let us teach you how to solve the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508299/case-statements-using-variables-not-working was my original question.

I eventually figured out something using a left outer join to connect the tables, you were right on with it implicitly being a cross join, thanks!